# One Year Later, Still Struggling with Unit vs Integration vs E2E testing

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, integration-testing, e2e-testing

I recently watched a number of talks from the AssertJS conference (which I highly recommend), among them @kentcdodds "[Write Tests, Not Too Many, Mostly Integration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fha2bVoC8SE&t=2s)." I've been working on an Angular project for over a year, have written some unit tests, and just started playing with Cypress, but I still feel this frustration around integration tests, and where to draw the lines. I'd really love to talk to some pro who does this day in and day out, but I don't know any where I work. Since I'm tired of not being able to figure this out, I thought I'd just ask the world here, cause you all are fantastic.

So in Angular (or React or Vue, etc), you have component code, and then you have the HTML template, and usually they interact in some way. The component code has functions in it that can be unit tested, and that part I'm ok with.

Where I haven't gotten things straight in my mind is, do you call it an integration test when you're testing how a component function changes the UI? If you're testing that kind of thing, should that be done just in E2E tests? Because Angular/Jasmine(or Jest) lets you do this kind of thing, referencing the UI:

```
const el = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('button'));
expect(el[0].nativeElement.textContent).toEqual('Submit')
```

But does that mean you should? And if you do, then do you not cover that in your E2E tests?

And regarding integration with things like services, how far do you go with integrating? If you mock the actual HTTP call, and just test that it would get called with the right functions, is that an integration test, or is it still a unit test?

To sum up, I intuitively know what I need to test to have confidence that things are working as they should, I'm just not sure how to discern when something requires all three kinds of tests or not.

I know this is getting long, but here's my example app:

[image: example app]

There's a property called `hasNoProducts` that is set after a product is chosen and data is returned from the server (or not if there is none). If `hasNoProducts` is true, UI (through an *ngIf) shows that "Sorry" message. If false, then other selections become available. Depending on the product picked, those options change.

So I know I can write a unit test and mock the HTTP request so that I can test that `hasNoProducts` is set correctly. But then, I want to test that the message is displayed, or that the additional options are displayed. And if there is data, test that switching the product changes the data in the other lists that would subsequently show on screen. If I do that using Angular/Jasmine, is it an integration test since I'm "integrating" component and template? If not, then what would be an integration test?

I could keep asking questions, but I'll stop there in the hopes that someone has read this far and has some insight. Again, I've read tons of articles, watched tons of videos and done tutorials, but every time I sit down to apply to a real project, I get stuck on things like this, and I want to get past this! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

What distinguishes unit-tests and integration-tests (and then subsystem-tests and system-tests) is the goal that you want to achieve with the tests.

The goal of unit-testing is to find those bugs in small pieces of code that can be found if these pieces of code are isolated.  Note that this does not mean you truly must isolate the code, but it means your *focus* is the isolated code.  In unit-testing, mocking is very common, since it allows to stimulate scenarios that otherwise are hard to test, or it speeds up build and execution times etc., but mocking is not mandatory: For example, you would not mock calls to a mathematical `sin()` function from the standard library, because the `sin()` function does not keep you from reaching your testing goals.  But, leaving the `sin()` function in does not turn these tests into integration tests.  Strictly speaking, you could even have unit-tests where some real network accesses take place (if you are too lazy to mock the network access), but due to the non-determinism, delays etc. these unit tests would be slow and unreliable, which means they would simply not be well suited to specifically find the bugs in the isolated code.  That's why everybody says that "if there is some real network access, it is not a unit-test", which is not formally but practically correct.

Since in unit-testing you intentionally only focus on the isolated code, you will not find bugs that are due to misunderstandings about interactions with other components.  If you mock some depended-on-component, then you implement these mocks based on your understanding of how the other component behaves.  If your understanding is wrong, your mock implementations will reflect your wrong understanding, and your unit-tests will succeed, although in the integrated system things will break.  That is not a flaw of unit-testing, but simply the reason why there are other test levels like integration testing.  In other words, even if you do unit-testing perfectly, there will unavoidably remain some bugs that unit-testing is not even intending to find.

Now, what are integration tests then?  They are defined by the goal to find bugs in the interactions between (already tested) components.  Such bugs can, for example, be due to mutual misconceptions of the developers of the components about how an interface is meant to work.  For example, in the case of a library component `B` that is used from `A`: Does `A` call functions from the right component `B` (rather than from `C`), do the calls happen while `B` is already in a proper state (`B` might not be initialized yet or in error state), do the calls happen in the proper order, are the arguments provided in the correct order and have values in the expected form (e.g. zero based index vs. one based index?, `null` allowed?), are the return values provided in the expected form (returned error code vs. exception) and have values in the expected form?  This is for one integration scenario - there are many others, like, components exchanging data via files (binary or text?  which end-of-line marker: unix, dos, ...?, ...).

There are many possible interaction errors.  To find them, in integration testing you integrate the real components (the real `A` and the real `B`, no mocks, but possibly mocks for other components) and stimulate them such that the different interactions actually take place - ideally in all interesting ways, like, trying to force some boundary cases in the interaction (exchanged file is empty, ...).  Again, just the fact that the test operates on a software where some components are integrated does not make it an integration test: Only if the test is specifically designed to initiate interactions such that bugs in these interactions become apparent, then it is an integration test.

Subsystem tests (which are the next level) then focus, again, on the remaining bugs, that is, those bugs which neither unit-testing nor integration testing intend to find.  Examples are requirements on the component `C` that were not considered when `C` was decomposed into `A` and `B`, or, if `C` is built using some outdated version of `A` where some bug was still in.  However, when climbing up from unit-testing via integration testing to subsystem testing and above, it is a challenge to stay focused: Only to have tests for bugs that could not have been found before, and not to, say, repeat unit-tests on subsystem level.

Comment: And what about the specific case that was mentioned in the question? The angular component should render the text "Sorry, that product has no items yet.". This text is shown if ```hasNoProducts``` is true. What should you test? Should you test that "hasNoproducts" is true? Should you test that the string is rendered? Should you test both? If I test that the text is rendered, that implies that the boolean is also set correctly so why should I test if the boolean is set?

Comment: Or, maybe, I should test that the boolean is set correctly and then, in a separate test, mock the boolean value and see that the HTML text is rendered accordingly?  Perhaps I should test all of the scenarios I described independently i.e.: test that the boolean is set correctly independent of whether the text is shown, test that the text is shown correctly regardless of the boolean's value and then test that the text is shown if and only if the boolean is true? Which of these cases represent a unit test vs integration test vs E2E?